# How to disable html angular attribute suggestions in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I simply want to remove these Angular suggestions in html files in Visual Studio 2019, since i dont use Angular.
[image]

Where can i do that? I tried to find it in under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML, but didn't seem to be there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is visual studio, not vs code.

Comment: Yes, its Visual Studio 2019, as i wrote?

Comment: I answered to a comment suggesting this to be about vscode. Seems that comment was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Save a backup copy of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Languages\Schemas\HTML\SchemaCatalog.xml` (just in case)

Step 2: Edit the above file to delete the following element:

```
  <schema File="angular.xsd" FriendlyName="AngularJS"
      Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/angular" IsSupplemental="true" CustomPrefix="ng-" />
```

Step 3: Restart Visual Studio

Comment: Tested on my Visual Studio (VS 2019 Enterprise) -- I think you'll need to change the path slightly if your you're running a different version.  Replace `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE` with the folder where `devenv.exe` is installed on your system.

Comment: I didn't have the SchemaCatalog.xml in that directory, but i had angular.xsd and angular16.png which i deleted, and now its gone. Thanks!